# How to make a text-to-speech app

Tags: windows, vbscript, text-to-speech

I'm a software engineer student and I need to do a text-to-speech app in vbs for my project. I coded it and it was very easy. The point is I want to make it possible to speak in French for example or in Russian. Can anyone help me? Making it speak in English is very easy.
This is the code:

```
Dim Message, Speak
Message=InputBox("Enter a text","The speaking App.")
Set Speak=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
Speak.Speak Message
```

Comment: See [SpVoice Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723602.aspx) documentation, particularly [SpVoice Voice property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723614.aspx).

Comment: This also might be of help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378476%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the text-to-speech voice on your computer? I think the text-to-speech api you are using only supports the voice/language set on the machine running the programme. If you need it to read text in another language, you may want to download some additional voices provided by Microsoft.

Comment: You mean as installing a language pack or something?